# Number as well as the digits of a number divisible by another number(say 3)

Tags: java, arrays

This is related to java.
I am trying to find out numbers in a range which are divisible a particular number say X. Also the digits of the number are divisible by the number X.
For Ex: Range 30 to 40
so the number 30,33,36,39 are divisible by 3 and also the digits are divisible by 3.
But in the code written form my end the loop logic seems not to be correct as it gives me only 30 and 33 as the output.
Can you please help me to understand this please?

Code:

```
public class Char{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        //Fill the code
        int m,n,i,z = 0;
        int x = 3;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the range for shipment numbers :");
        m = sc.nextInt();
        n = sc.nextInt();
        //while (m!=0 && n!=0){
        System.out.println("Possible shipment numbers :");
            for (i=m;i<=n;i++){
                if(i%10==z){
                    if(z%x==0);
                    z=i/10;
                    System.out.println(i);
                    }

                }


            }

}
```

Code:

Comment: Do you mean that the sum of the digits should be divisible by 3? Because that's true of all multiples of 3.

Comment: Hi @jsheeran, the number and its digits..for example the valid num is 36 as the number and its digits both are divisible by 3. But the number 15 is not valid as the digits of the number(1 and 5) are not divisible by 3. Thanks

Comment: Is `x` ever going to be anything other than 3? Because you're going to have a very narrow set of results if it's greater than 5.

Comment: @jsheeran, X can be any number...just that the logic would be that the number as well as its digits should be divisible by X

Comment: You would make it easier for us — increasing the chance of a good answer — if you use explanatory variable names and indent your code properly. I suggest `divisor`, `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over *each digit* of the main loop's variable, **i**. You need an inner loop (the 'while' below) to check each digit of **i**:

```
    int m, n, i, z = 0;
    int x = 3;
    boolean div;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the range for shipment numbers :");
    m = sc.nextInt();
    n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Possible shipment numbers :");
    for (i = m; i <= n; i++) {
        z = i;
        div = true;
        while (z > 0) {
            if (z % 10 % x != 0) {
                div = false;
                break;
            }
            z /= 10;
        }
        if (div) System.out.println(i);
    }
```

Now this works for much larger number ranges as well. So for example, a run gives:

> Enter the range for shipment numbers : 300 400 Possible shipment
>   numbers : 300 303 306 309 330 333 336 339 360 363 366 369 390 393 396
>   399

Comment: Correct answer as far as I can tell. A bit too much spoon-feeding for my taste.